# 1000s of Management Queues in Artemis Web Console

Tags: activemq-artemis

I'm using the management API for ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0 to get the count on 1 queue using the following code;

```
    val message = session!!.createMessage(false)
    ManagementHelper.putAttribute(message, "queue.$queueName", "messageCount")
    val requestor = ClientRequestor(session, "activemq.management")
    val reply = requestor.request(message)
    val count = (ManagementHelper.getResult(reply) as Long).toInt()
```

However, this code runs every 30 seconds so after about an hour it results in 1000s of new temporary queues being created which in turn, pollutes and slows the Management Console. Is there anyway to remove these queues (or better yet not have them created when retrieving the message count)? (Note: The queues are removed once the service is restarted)

[image]

Comment: @JustinBertram - 2.17.0 and your suggestion worked. thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to call `close()` on your `requestor` so that the underlying temporary queue used to implement the request-reply pattern is removed.

I created a test in the ActiveMQ Artemis test-suite and the only way I could get it to fail was by *not* calling `close()` on `requestor`:

```java
package org.apache.activemq.artemis.tests.integration;

import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.*;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.client.*;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.management.ManagementHelper;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.ActiveMQServer;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.tests.util.ActiveMQTestBase;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SimpleTest extends ActiveMQTestBase {

   protected ActiveMQServer server;
   protected ClientSession session;
   protected ClientSessionFactory sf;
   protected ServerLocator locator;

   @Override
   @Before
   public void setUp() throws Exception {
      super.setUp();
      server = createServer(false, createDefaultInVMConfig());
      server.start();
   }

   @Test
   public void simpleTest() throws Exception {
      locator = ActiveMQClient.createServerLocatorWithoutHA(new TransportConfiguration(INVM_CONNECTOR_FACTORY));
      sf = locator.createSessionFactory();
      session = sf.createSession(false, true, true);
      session.start();
      server.createQueue(new QueueConfiguration("myQueue"));

      long start = server.getPostOffice().getAllBindings().count();
      for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
         ClientMessage message = session.createMessage(false);
         ManagementHelper.putAttribute(message, "queue.myQueue", "messageCount");
         ClientRequestor requestor = new ClientRequestor(session, "activemq.management");
         requestor.request(message);
         requestor.close(); // if I remove this line the test fails
      }
      assertEquals(0, server.getPostOffice().getAllBindings().count() - start);
   }
}
```